# 3 displays, linux mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, nvidia, display-settings

I have a laptop Acer Aspive V3-771G with GeForce 740M. I want make my laptop to output information on 3 displays (laptop's display + I have 2 external monitors), but I can't do that because of errors, this is what I get:

- http://screencloud.net/v/qeqj

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1920x1080      60.0 +   59.9     40.0  
1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
1600x1024      60.2  
1400x1050      60.0  
1280x1024      60.0  
1440x900       59.9  
1280x960       60.0  
1360x768       59.8     60.0  
1152x864       60.0  
1024x768       60.0  
800x600        60.3     56.2  
640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
1920x1200      60.0*+
1920x1080      60.0 +
1600x1200      60.0  
1680x1050      60.0  
1280x1024      60.0  
1280x960       60.0  
1024x768       60.0  
800x600        60.3  
640x480        60.0  
720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
1920x1200      60.0*+
1600x1200      60.0  
1680x1050      59.9  
1280x1024      60.0  
1280x960       60.0  
1024x768       60.0  
800x600        60.3  
640x480        60.0  
720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

lspci output: http://screencloud.net/v/pFFy

I'm using Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon (based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Thanks!